# scrlayer-scrpage: Header/Footer only lasts for one page when used in subfiles

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, input, standalone, scrlayer-scrpage

If I use a [`scrlayer-scrpage`](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)-style header/footer command (such as `\chead`)
at the end of a [`standalone`](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf) subfile,
the header or footer command does not issue.

Does anyone know why this occurs and how to prevent it?

Note that header2/footer2 commands posted in
`00-TitlePage` and `01-HeaderFooter` do not trigger.

Also note that the initial header1/footer1 commands in `00-TitlePage`
reset on page 2.

(Run the MasterFile, although any of the other files can be run independently,
except for the Preamble.)

### MasterFile.tex

```
\documentclass[crop=false,float=true,class=scrartcl]{standalone}

\providecommand{\main}{.}
\input{\main/Subfiles/Preamble.tex}                     % Preamble [document configuration]

\chead{HeaderMasterPre}

\begin{document}

%\chead{HeaderMaster}

\input{\main/Subfiles/00-TitlePage}
\input{\main/Subfiles/01-HeaderFooter}
\input{\main/Subfiles/02-Main}

\end{document}
```

### Preamble.tex

```
\usepackage{standalone}                 % allows for independent runs of subfiles.
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\chead{HeaderPreamble}
```

### 00-TitlePage.tex

```
\documentclass[crop=false,float=true,class=scrartcl]{standalone}

\providecommand{\main}{..}
\input{\main/Subfiles/Preamble.tex}                     % Preamble [document configuration]

\chead{HeaderTitlePagePre}

\begin{document}

\chead{HeaderTitlePage}

\begin{center}
\Huge{ \textbf{Title} }
\end{center}

\clearpage

\chead{HeaderTitlePageCP}

\end{document}
```

### 01-HeaderFooter.tex

```
\documentclass[crop=false,float=true,class=scrartcl]{standalone}

\providecommand{\main}{..}
\input{\main/Subfiles/Preamble.tex}                     % Preamble [document configuration]

\chead{HeaderHeaderFooterPre}

\begin{document}

\chead{HeaderHeaderFooter}

\end{document}
```

### 02-Main.tex

```
\documentclass[crop=false,float=true,class=scrartcl]{standalone}

\providecommand{\main}{..}
\input{\main/Subfiles/Preamble.tex}                     % Preamble [document configuration]

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it is because of grouping

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Grouping in my code, something to do with processing? Is there something I can do about it?

Comment: Realistically, I want to know what `scrlayer` is doing - I don't understand what causes it to decide when the command is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Before the explanation, and because the solution is not very elegant, I do propose a different solution. For multifile-projects, where you want to combine the possibility of typesetting each file individually, and being able to connect everything quickly, look into the `subfiles`-package. I believe the grouping behaviour explained below is not present here, but I might be wrong.

#### Grouping

> Disclaimer: In the following answer, I will only look at the centre header. The other header and footer items would, of course, have a similar approach.

This is because the variables `\chead{text}` and its friends are store locally, within a group. When there are `standalone` documents, they all use `\begin{document} and` \end{document}, which is a group, meaning that the change would only be within that. After the group is ended, the variable is restored to its previous value. It's like writing `\begin{group}\chead{text}\end{group}`, which wouldn't result in any noticeable change.

#### Solution: Global variables

What we can do is set a global variable, using `\gdef`. These variables are carried over everywhere. Without changing the definition of `\chead{}` and friends, let's instead create a new variable, with a macro as a shortcut for easier input.

```
\gdef\zcenterHead{}
\newcommand{\centerHead}[1]{\gdef\zcenterHead{#1}}
\chead{\centerHead}
```

Now we can use the command `\centerHead{}` to store a global variable. The `\chead{\zcenterHead}` will only be set once, and will retrieve the global variable.

In your document, to change the centre header, use the macro `\centerHead{text}`.

#### MasterFile.text

```
\documentclass[crop=false,float=true,class=scrartcl]{standalone}
\gdef\centerHead{}
\providecommand{\main}{.}
\input{Preamble}
\chead{\centerHead}
\usepackage{lipsum}                 % Preamble [document configuration]

\begin{document}
\input{00-TitlePage}

\section{nono}
hello
\input{01-HeaderFooter}
\input{02-Main}

\end{document}
```

#### 00-TitlePage.tex

```
\documentclass[crop=false,float=true,class=scrartcl]{standalone}

\providecommand{\main}{..}
\input{\main/Subfiles/Preamble.tex}                     % Preamble [document configuration]

\begin{document}

\centerHead{oh yo}
\cfoot{Footer1}

\begin{center}
\Huge{ \textbf{Title} }
\end{center}

\clearpage

\centerHead{Header2a}
\cfoot{Footer2a}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Most dope. Thus, use of `\centerhead` redefines the global variable regardless of which subfile the code is embedded?

Comment: that would be correct. I think a more elegant solution could show up, so I would wait with accepting this one.